# Delivring a project in a VM(LINUX)

Tags: linux, joomla

I have a project to work on using *Joomla*
So, My question is can I do the work in *Windows* and then deliver it in a *VM(LINUX)*, or I have no choice,I have to do it in *VM(LINUX)*.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. 
You can set .htaccess and url friendly when you put it on Linux, the only thing that changes

Comment: Thanks for answering